# Export all figures and plots produced from a Wolfram script into a single PDF

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, scripting

Here is a `.wls` script that produces different images into `.jpg` format. I would like
to export directly all the images in a same and unique pdf page(s) like if we could directly print them into a `Latex` report : is it possible ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

Print@"The aim of this small program is to calculate Einstein`s \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(G\), \(\[Mu]\[Nu]\)]\)= \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(\[Mu]\[Nu]\)]\)-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(\(\[Mu]\[Nu]\)\(\[IndentingNewLine]\)
\)]\) Tensor. "
Print@"Line Element in General Relativity defined as  \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ds\), \(2\)]\)= \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(\[Mu]\[Nu]\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(dX\), \(\[Mu]\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(dX\), \(\[Nu]\)]\) , where \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(\[Mu]\[Nu]\)]\) is covariant metric and \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(X\), \(\[Mu]\)]\) contravariant coordinates. Contravariant of metric defined as inverse of its"
X={t,r,\[Theta],\[Phi]};
CovariantMetric={{c^2,0,0,0},{0,-(a[t]^2/(1-K^2 r^2)),0,0},{0,0,-a[t]^2 r^2,0},{0,0,0,-a[t]^2 r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};
Export["pics/LCDM_CovariantMetric.jpg", Rasterize[MatrixForm[CovariantMetric]//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
ContravariantMetric=Inverse[CovariantMetric];
Export["pics/LCDM_ContravariantMetric.jpg", Rasterize[MatrixForm[ContravariantMetric]//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
XContravariant=FullSimplify[Table[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(mu = 1\), \(4\)]\(ContravariantMetric[\([mu, nu]\)] X[\([mu]\)]\)\),{nu,1,4}]];
Export["pics/LCDM_XContravariant.jpg", Rasterize[XContravariant//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
Print@"Christoffel Symbol: \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(jl\), \(i\)]\)=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(im\)]\)(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(l\)]\) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(mj\)]\) + \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(j\)]\) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(ml\)]\)-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(m\)]\) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(jl\)]\))"

ChristoffelSymbol[i_,j_,l_]:= 1/2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(4\)]\(ContravariantMetric[\([i, m]\)]*\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(X[\([j]\)]\)]\ CovariantMetric[\([m, l]\)] + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(X[\([l]\)]\)]\ CovariantMetric[\([m, j]\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(X[\([m]\)]\)]\ CovariantMetric[\([j, l]\)])\)\)\);
i=1;
tb = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[i,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
Export["pics/LCDM_tb_i_1.jpg", Rasterize[tb//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
i=2;
tb = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[i,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
Export["pics/LCDM_tb_i_2.jpg", Rasterize[tb//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
i=3;
tb = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[i,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
Export["pics/LCDM_tb_i_3.jpg", Rasterize[tb//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
i=4;
tb = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[i,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
Export["pics/LCDM_tb_i_4.jpg", Rasterize[tb//TraditionalForm, RasterSize->3000, ImageSize->2000]]
Pause[5]
```

If someone could know how to do it, this would be fine to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to first create JPG pictures and then converting them to PDF. You can export directly to PDF. E.g.

```
tb1 = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[1,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
tb2 = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[2,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
tb3 = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[3,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];
tb4 = Table[ChristoffelSymbol[4,j,l],{j, 1,4},{l,1,4}];

Export["d:/tmp/test.pdf", Column[{tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4}]]
```

This produces a PDF file with the content:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to print also some text between the equations to make the things more explicit ? since I have to explain which is the current step when I begin a demonstration . Best regards

Comment: Simply write e.g.: `Column[{tb1, "some text", tb2, "more text", tb3, tb4}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion !